# AspNetCoreRateLimit - Limits Not Working for individual endpoints as per custom configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, endpoint, rate-limiting, api-throttling

`I'm Trying to set limits For all API , for some API i wish to have different limit , but i dont want to whitelist . say, all the get method based api should be triggered only 5 per minute but "get :/api/test/testlog " can be triggered for more than 15 per minute
i m using AspNetCoreRateLimit NuGet

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q1WW.png)

for me the first rule alone is working the second rule is not working. `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.